# Editable HTML content is very laggy when it is large

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, contenteditable

For example, I have the following simple HTML page, where the `<span>[SOME FIELD]</span>` is repeating many times to make up for about 200K of the file size:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body editableContent="true">
        <span>[SOME FIELD]</span>
        <span>[SOME FIELD]</span>
...
        <span>[SOME FIELD]</span>
</body>
</html>
```

As the content grows, the editing experience is becoming very laggy. It's literally impossible to type or edit the content.

Here is a **[complete repro case](http://goo.gl/rFuoqn)**. To see what I mean, just move the cursor to the end of the editable content and try editing. **It lags big time under IE and Chrome**, making it almost impossible to type. **It works great under Firefox**, though.

**The problem:** I need to get it working reasonably fast under IE.

So far, I got close with IE8 emulation (with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`), so [this](http://goo.gl/2VqHyD) works (under IE).

However, I need to support `IE=edge`, too. Any advice on how to make this happen would be greatly appreciated. IMO, it's a bug (which I submitted [here for IE](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/925659/editable-content-editablecontent-true-is-tremendously-laggy-for-ie9-and-later) and [here for Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=396051)), but I'm looking for any workaround.

**Updated**, a bounty is offered for any solution that works while loaded in stand-alone IE browser or a custom application hosting [WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/webbrowser-control/info), using `IE=edge` HTML document mode.

**Updated**, the corresponding [IE bug reported](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/925659/editable-content-editablecontent-true-is-tremendously-laggy-for-ie9-and-later) was just closed as "Won't fix".

Comment: If it is simple content, do you think you could use a disguised multiline textbox for your editable content, and add the markup through javascript on `blur`?

Comment: @UweB, nope. The user has to be able to select blocks, use copy/paste, and eventually have more complex HTML like e.g. tables. Also, I have to stick with plain HTML (despite HTML5 Canvas could be really cool: http://earwicker.com/carota).

Comment: Looks like this *used* to be an issue in Firefox too... https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=635618

Comment: How about using AJAX,database and pagination?

Comment: @MikeAnte, I can't see how AJAX/pagination can help with editable content. In reality, it's a full-featured editor similar to Word. E.g, it has a contextual spellchecker, which depends on the words around the cursor. Or how the user can select a block of text that spans multiple pages.

Comment: It's one of those things that is hard to do (for browservendors). Will probably improve 'in the future'. For more info on why this is difficult: https://medium.com/medium-eng/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480

Comment: @user1120808, it's getting better in other browsers, at least in Firefox. However, it'd be a big hassle for us to switch from hosting Trident to Gecko in our custom desktop app.

Comment: Don't use directely the contenteditable attribute but use a wysiwyg HTML editor instead like tinyMCE, html5edit or Mercury. They are built to work with large chunks of HTML data and work with all modern browsers.

Comment: @Noseratio Selecting a character and then deleting it will return the editing speed to normal in IE. Maybe you could try to do this programmatically?

Comment: @Teemu, actually selecting a single character, then simply simulating a Home keystroke seems to stop the lagginess in IE. This is the best solution so far, thank you. Feel free to post this as a answer and I'll reward it with the bounty.

Comment: @Noseratio I think it's `contenteditable`, not `editableContent`

Comment: @Noseratio Do you mean ActiveX is acceptable?

Comment: @Temu, you don't need to actually implement it, I've already done that and it works. Just post you comment as an answer. Cheers.

Comment: The "SendKey" workaround doesn't work reliably and the [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/925659/editable-content-editablecontent-true-is-tremendously-laggy-for-ie9-and-later) has been closed as "won't fix". As much as we loved `WebBrowser`, this has actually forced us to abandon it for HTML editing and look elsewhere, cc @JonathanSampson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting a character with mouse or <kbd>SHIFT + ARROW</kbd> and then deleting by hitting <kbd>DELETE</kbd> will return the editing speed to normal in IE.

Comment: This answer gets the bounty. I'd be more than happy to offer another bounty for a more elegant solution (paging, etc) that would *actually work* and provide seamless editing experience, similar to the native editing.

Comment: @Noseratio I've removed the code not working for you. I had a simplified test case, and it seemed to work fine in it.

Comment: Just a note to others, simply selecting a character then simulating the Home or an arrow keystroke also eliminates the slowness.

Answer (score 3):

Why not break the data down and store it in an array or Json object and only read a portion at a time, updating as the user scrolls or moves through the content. This way only a small portion will being processed at any point in time. If you use Jquery you could get the id from the class reference. If you don't want to use Jquery you could write a class identifier function in raw Javascript. The below is rough but you can get the idea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body editableContent="true">
    <span id="item1" class="handle_items">[SOME FIELD]</span>
    <span id="item2" class="handle_items">[SOME FIELD]</span>
    ...
    <span id="item-n" class="handle_items">[SOME FIELD]</span>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(function(){

    var arrayData = [];

    $(".handle_items").mouseover(function() {
        var identVar = $( this ).prop('id');
        fillHtml(identVar);
    });

    function fillHtml(identVar) {
        $("#" + identVar).html(arrayData[i]);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: There was a similar comment to the question, so I'd copy my reply: I can't see how AJAX/pagination can help with editable content. In reality, it's a full-featured editor similar to Word. E.g, it has a contextual spellchecker, which depends on the words around the cursor. Or how the user can navigate through and select a block of text that spans multiple pages. Thanks anyway!

Comment: My example is an innerHtml pagination but the same technique can be used to write the data to arrays as well. Thus breaking it into smaller pieces and only dealing with the data visible to the user. I use this technique all the time to improve performance. If you have content spanning multiple pages I would think organizing the JSON format and assembling content as required while recording the data's location would work. I often store location data in the id and use the information to determine how to handle the data. Anyway, sry it didn't help. :-( GL

Comment: I understand the concept, but I'm not sure if it can be used to implement a seamless user editing experience similar to my [native example](http://goo.gl/rFuoqn) (i.e, multi-line text stream selection, undo/redo, scrolling etc) but without lagging. If you could post a proof-of-concept code that actually works this way, I'd be happy to reward it with another 500. Meanwhile, my workaround of choice is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27936312/1768303).

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to not use `contenteditable = true` for entire area (body section in your case). You can determine the visible area of the body, create a '[Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)' for the respective area and temporarily wrap it in an element with `contenteditable = true`.

However, depending on more detailed requirements, this approach might not be suitable.
For example, one problem that comes to my mind is trying to maintain caret position after scrolling only a few rows.

Comment: We actually have considered this, but the main problem would be cross-section selection, when you want to start selection from one editable div, and finish in another editable div. That's besides the issue with regular arrow key navigation across editable divs. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of blind shooting, I think I've found something that might actually work:

1. Copy the large chunk of HTML into the clipboard
2. Paste it over whatever content is inside the editable area
3. Voilà, the lagging while editing seems to have been gone

Presumably, both steps can be done programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

In all browsers the more elements the slower they get. The other thing that causes problems are memory leaks. Most large frameworks, like angular or knockout cause memory leaks. You can profile those by running a memory snapshot in the memory profiler.

As far as elements you really want to keep that under a thousand I'd you can. You can add and remove elements as needed they way good continuous scrollers do.

Comment: The memory footprint with either IE or Chrome for [my test case](http://goo.gl/4b6Mo8) is reasonable, same as the CPU usage, which doesn't even reach its peaks. Why would it be laggy?

Comment: I was debugging the same issue in CKEditor recently (http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12062)... ah, and we met there already :).

Comment: @Reinmar, that was my one of my colleagues, so nice to meet you :)

Answer (score 1):

I have no IE to check performance right now, anyway in Chrome (Ubuntu) this do help. I just remove `contenteditable` from root element and add it to each `span`.

This make content editing pretty fast.

You can check this is Chrome with next steps:

1. in devtools (elements panel) select root node of editor (that is `body` with `contenteditable` attribute)
2. got to devtools javascript console
3. execute this code snippet:

Snippet:

```
var nodes = $0.querySelectorAll('span');
$0.setAttribute('contenteditable', false)
for (var i = 0, max = nodes.length; i < max; i++) {
    nodes[i].setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the text block selection (Shift + Arrow keys) doesn't works across multiple `contenteditable=true` SPANs in either Chrome or IE. Moreover, with this approach in IE you cannot navigate up and down between lines.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you didn't want to use pagination because...

> I can't see how AJAX/pagination can help with editable content. In reality, it's a full-featured editor similar to Word. E.g, it has a contextual spellchecker, which depends on the words around the cursor. Or how the user can select a block of text that spans multiple pages.

However, you can use pagination (or something similar) while still allowing these features. Basically, you need to only load the **currently relevant** lines.

I know Objective-C, and this problem is very similar to UITableViewControllers. They combat the issue by displaying the table elements that are currently being viewed, and deallocating the others. In your case, you would want to store their information in a JavaScript array.

The way I would go about it is to create a `loadItem` function and an `unloadItem` function. `loadItem` would get the contents of an item and add it to the body, and `unloadItem` would copy the contents back to the array and remove the item (probably by setting the style `visibility:hidden`, but I haven't checked to see if it works).

To find the currently relevant lines:

- Anything that is on the screen
- Anything that is part of a selection
- Anything else that might come up that should be displayed

As lines are unselected, go off the screen, or anything else that renders them no longer needed, call `unloadItem()` and pass it the line number/whatever identifies the line.

**EDIT:** This is what I mean:

```js
for(var count=0;count<1000;count++){
  document.getElementById("main").innerHTML+="<span id='item"+count+"'>[SOME FIELD "+count+"]</span>";
}

function loadItem(number){
  document.getElementById("item"+number).style.visibility="visible";
}
function unloadItem(number){
  document.getElementById("item"+number).style.visibility="hidden";
}

unloadItem(1);
unloadItem(2);
loadItem(1);

// I didn't have time to implement the rest. Basically, when a user is not viewing a line, it should be hidden. When they scroll to view it, it should show up again. I haven't tested this yet, but it should work.

// There is supposed to be a bit of slowness when it loads, it is creating all the content and that is normal.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body contenteditable="true" id="main">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement all this and still keep the intuitive MS Word-like editing experience. Sounds like creating an editor from scratch. There're existing projects like this (e.g. http://earwicker.com/carota) but their performance with large HTML content leaves a lot to be desired. Anyhow, if you could take my [repro case](http://goo.gl/rFuoqn) and show what you mean with a live proof-of-concept (with Undo/Redo, multi-line text stream selection etc), I'd greatly appreciate that.

Comment: @Noseratio I added an example. Didn't have time to make everything work, but hopefully it is enough to demonstrate the idea. Not a whole lot of changes will really need to be made, actually.

Comment: Sorry, this code snippet doesn't help at all (I do know how to control a visibility of an HTML element). If you can post some code that **actually provides the same user editing experience as http://goo.gl/rFuoqn but without lagging**, I'll reward it with another 500. Meanwhile, the solution of my choice is the one posted by @Teemu in the comments to the question.

Answer (score -1):

1. I think you should make each span tag editable and show limited number of spans at a time . this will help in better loading of your web page. and content will be easily editable .
2. additionally you can do editableContent="true" if user wants to edit more than one span tag at the same time time. which is a bit surprising because if your file contains 200k size , someone will rarely edit multiple content at same time. whenever a user clicks to edit whole webpage, create a pop up with simple basic html layout and let user to change whatever he wants. it will load properly in basic layout popup window.